# One Django Form in Multiple Views with Inherited Post Request

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I haven't found any definitive documentation on this, but I have a contact form that I need to use in the sidebar in multiple views.  Currently my code is dirty because I am repeating the code snippet below in multiple views to process the form. Is there a way to place the Post Request in a template that can be inherited?

View

```
def contact(request):
    form_class = ContactForm

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Thank you, we have received your message.')

        if form.is_valid():
        ...
```

Thank you for your  help.

Comment: I do not know what you *really* mean by saying *inheriting a form*, but I think class-based views might help you. | But in case you mean that you do not always want to repeat your code above, this might help you: https://codeshare.io/ZN7nx

Comment: Bloody brilliant!!  I got hung up for a few minutes, then realized I had to put `{'form': ContactForm}` in my `contact` function.  Can you place the code share as an answer for me to accept as correct?  Also, if you don't mind, can you point to some documentation on the `(req, msg)` part of your code? I searched but couldn't see where this was coming from.  Thanks again!!

Comment: It's not something on a documentation. You simply created a function and passed `request`, `message` and `form_class` as argument. That's all. I'll answer a while later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I'm assuming you do the same operation as below while every view is run:

```
def contact(request):
    # First you choose the form.
    form_class = ContactForm

    # Then you want to know if request is POST type
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # You take the form data from given POST
        form = form_class(data=request.POST)
        # You add message to messages.
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'Thank you, we have received your message.')
```

If you do the same over and over again, you can create your own function at the beginning of your `views.py` file of any app to make it short and [not to repeat yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/misc/design-philosophies/#don-t-repeat-yourself-dry) again and again.

```
def take_message(request, form, messages, message):
    if request.METHOD == "POST":
        # I'm reinitializing <form> variable here.
        form = form(data=request.POST)
        # That <message> variable below must be a string, then you can dynamically pass your message.
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, message)
```

Then use it in your view:

```
def contact(request):
    take_message(request, ContactForm, messages, "Thanks, we got your message.")
    # And the rest here.
```

---

However, I recommend for you to use [class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/class-based-views/) since they can handle any request types as method. So, I'm changing that `take_message` method as below:

```
def take_message(request, form, messages, message):
    # I'm reinitializing <form> variable here.
    form = form(data=request.POST)
    # That <message> variable below must be a string, then you can dynamically pass your message.
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, message)
```

Then, my view is as below:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
# And any other important imports.

# ...

class ContactView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "contact.html" # This is your template.

    def get(self, request):
        # Do things when the method is GET. Like, viewing current messages in a hypothetical admin template.

    def delete(self, request):
        # Do things when the method is DELETE. Don't forget to use authentication here, so only superuser can delete messages.

    def post(self, request):
        # Do things when the method is POST.
        # I'm assuming anonymous users can send messages, so there's no need for authentication here.
        take_message(request, ContactForm, messages, "Thanks you, we got your message.")
        # Other things to do.

# urls.py
url(r"^contact/$", ContactView.as_view(), name="contact-page")
```